# How to redirect one visitor IP address to a specified page on my website

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to use .htaccess to redirect a visitor with a specified IP address to always be redirected to a specified page when visiting any page on my website. I've tried the code below but it is causing an error. I'm using a wordpress site.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/specified-page/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|js) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^1\.2\.3\.4
RewriteRule $ /specified-page/ [R=302,L]
```

It is causing "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" message.

As a side-note, my domain is pointing to a sub-folder in my webspace. As are some other websites. This is all directed from another .htaccess file in the root of my webspace with code like this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.)?mydomain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mywebsitefolder1/
RewriteRule (.*) /mywebsitefolder1/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.)?mydomain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mywebsitefolder2/
RewriteRule (.*) /mywebsitefolder2/$1 [L]
```

and so on...

(The .htaccess I'm trying to edit to create the IP redirect is in 'mywebsitefolder1' folder.)

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work " ? Is the target ip address still able to access your site?

Comment: Apologies, yes the ip address can still see the whole website as normal.

Comment: Did you place this above your WordPress rule block in htaccess?

Comment: I've tried above and below and both times the IP can see the whole webpage. Just to check, does it need to be encapsulated by 
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    </IfModule>

Comment: `^1\.\2\.3\.4` - I realise this is just an example, but this is escaped incorrectly. If you've made the same mistake on the actual IP address then it will never match (although you'd expect the regex compile to fail, which would result in a 500 error). You have one too backslash escapes. The `\2` is an internal backreference, which doesn't exist in this example. No, you should not use the `<IfModule>` wrapper. What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: A little progress, it's now having an effect however, it returns an error message "redirected you too many times" rather than displaying the page.

Comment: "A little progress" - but you appear to have _negated_ the check for the IP address? Now your rule will only apply to every other IP address, not the one you are specifically targeting!? But if you are now getting a redirect loop then it suggests the check for the IP address is/was wrong to begin with. (?) You should also be using `REMOTE_ADDR` (as you had previously), not `REMOTE_HOST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/specified-page/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|js) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^1\.2\.3\.4
RewriteRule ^ /specified-page/? [R=302,L]
```

This will also remove an optional query string that could cause the redirect loop.

---

You have indeed a looping condition. Let's try it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^1\.2\.3\.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/specified-page/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|js) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /mywebsitefolder1/specified-page/ [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.)?mydomain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mywebsitefolder1/
RewriteRule (.*) /mywebsitefolder1/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.)?mydomain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mywebsitefolder2/
RewriteRule (.*) /mywebsitefolder2/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've tried that ans still get the too many redirects error. See my edit of my original post. I have added more information about other redirects for domains etc which may be causing the issue?

Comment: @Matt thanks for your response. I will look into it but I am busy right now. Have to pull my answer meanwhile.